# Unable to Load Category Tree after creating Category Programmatically

Tags: magento2, category

I have created a new category using the script below. Once I have created the category using the script, then added a subcategory through admin, The category checkbox tree will not load on the Catalog Price Rules page.

Marketing->Catalog Price Rules->Add New Rule->Conditions->(+)->Please Select a Condition to Add->Category->(...)->(open Chooser)(This is the option right next to the input field

It appears there is an error causing the script to reload the category in an infinite loop.

```
<?php
//creating categories in magento 2
//last verified Magento 2.2.0  27 Oct 2017
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
echo 'code by harshvardhanmalpani';
include('./app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
function createCategory($a='',$b=1,$c=true,$d='',$e='',$f='',$g='') {
        global $objectManager;
        $category = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create();
        $category->setName($a);
        $category->setParentId($b); // 1: root category.
        $category->setIsActive($c);
        $category->setCustomAttributes([
'description' => $d,
'meta_title' => $e,
'meta_keywords' => $f,
'meta_description' => $g,
]);
$objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface')->save($category);
}
createCategory("Abc");
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing to set root category/parent category.

Comment: Is the root category id indeed of 1 ? Have a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/36560/7773 to get it

Comment: The parent category is 1. I am adding a root category, and it will be for a new store, so there is no store at the time the category is created. I do link it to the store during the store creation process.

Comment: I have looked into this a little further. In the file vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/js/category-checkbox-tree.js there is a for loop that increments the first few times, but gets stuck after that.